# kafka stream - remove topic from the topology

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka stream application which consumes from 2 input topics. This has been running on production for a while.

Due to a new feature request, I will need to update the topology to ONLY consume from 1 topic. The code change is very straightforward, however I don't know if there are any side-effect after I drop one input topic from the topology while keeping the same "application.id".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the application is doing with the topics. If the application is reading the topics and calculate/filter values between them, then it will have an issue. However, if the application is using the topic's data independently then it shouldn't be an issue.